# Сумма значений полей в отдельном блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько динамически генерируемых блоков с полями.
Задача посчитать сумму значений полей в каждом отдельном блоке с учетом изменений значений отдельного поля этого блока.
Скрипт написал, однако он показывает результат сложения всех полей всех блоков.

```js
var i = $('input').size() + 1;
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('<div class="calc-row"><div class="input-wrap" style="vertical-align: top;"><select name="" id=""><optgroup label="B2C"><option value="Охрана квартир" data-service="250" selected>Охрана квартир</option><option value="Охрана дома" data-service="350">Охрана дома</option><option value="Охрана гаража" data-service="300">Охрана гаража</option><option value="Охрана загородного дома" data-service="400">Охрана загородного дома</option><option value="Охрана дачи" data-service="350">Охрана дачи</option></optgroup><optgroup label="B2B"><option value="Охрана торгового павильона/киоска" data-service="300">Охрана торгового павильона/киоска</option><option value="Охрана магазина" data-service="350">Охрана магазина</option><option value="Охрана офиса" data-service="350">Охрана офиса</option><option value="Охрана склада" data-service="400">Охрана склада</option><option value="Охрана торгового центра" data-service="500">Охрана торгового центра</option><option value="Охрана производсвенных строений" data-service="400">Охрана производсвенных строений</option><option value="Охрана других объектов" data-service="350">Охрана других объектов</option><option value="Наблюдение за пожарной сигнализацией" data-service="250">Наблюдение за пожарной сигнализацией</option><option value="Обслуживание за пожарной сигнализации" data-service="150">Обслуживание за пожарной сигнализации</option><option value="Обслуживание систем видеонаблюдения" data-service="300">Обслуживание систем видеонаблюдения</option></optgroup></select></div><div class="input-wrap"><label for="">Тревожная кнопка</label><input type="number" min="2" value="2" data-alert="100" /></div><div class="input-wrap"><label for="">СМС Оповещение</label><input type="number" min="1" value="1" data-sms="50" /></div><div class="input-wrap"><label for="">Доп инфоуслуги</label><input type="number" min="0" value="0" data-extra="50" /></div><div class="input-wrap"><label for="">Ответственность</label><select name="" id=""><option value="1000-5000">1000-5000</option><option value="1000-5000">5000-10000</option><option value="1000-5000">10000-15000</option></select></div><div class="res"></div></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.calc-3');
  i++;
});
$('.calc-3').on('change', '.input-wrap select, .input-wrap input[type=number]', function() {
  $('.calc-row select').each(function() {
    var val1 = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  });
  var sum = 0;
  $('.calc-row .input-wrap input[type=number]').each(function() {
    var val2 = $(this).val();
    sum += +val2;
    $('.res').text(sum);
  });
});
```

```css
.res {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.calc-wrap {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.calc-wrap .input-wrap,
.calc-wrap .input-rad-wrap,
.calc-wrap input[type=button] {
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.calc-wrap .input-rad-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.calc-wrap .input-rad-wrap input[type=radio] {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

.calc-wrap .input-rad-wrap input[type=radio]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.calc-wrap .input-wrap label,
.calc-wrap .input-wrap input {
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}

.calc-wrap .input-wrap input,
.calc-wrap .input-wrap select {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 40px;
}

.calc-wrap .input-wrap input[type=text],
.calc-wrap .input-wrap select {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.calc-wrap h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.calc-wrap h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* calc-3 */

.calc-wrap-3 {
  width: 90%;
}

.calc-wrap-3 .calc-row {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  display: -webkit-flex !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.calc-wrap-3 .calc-row select {
  width: 100%;
}

.calc-wrap-3 .calc-row input {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.calc-wrap-3 .calc-row p {
  min-width: 85%;
}

.calc-wrap-3 .calc-row .label-wrap {
  width: 30%;
}

.label-wrap label:last-child {
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc-wrap calc-wrap-3">
  <h2>Охрана</h2>
  <div class="calc-3">
    <button id="add">Добавить</button>
    <div class="calc-row">
      <div class="input-wrap" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <select name="" id="">
            <optgroup label="B2C">
              <option value="Охрана квартир" data-service="250" selected>Охрана квартир</option>
              <option value="Охрана дома" data-service="350">Охрана дома</option>
              <option value="Охрана гаража" data-service="300">Охрана гаража</option>
              <option value="Охрана загородного дома" data-service="400">Охрана загородного дома</option>
              <option value="Охрана дачи" data-service="350">Охрана дачи</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrap">
        <label for="">Тревожная кнопка</label>
        <input type="number" min="2" value="2" data-alert="100" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrap">
        <label for="">СМС Оповещение</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" value="1" data-sms="50" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrap">
        <label for="">Доп инфоуслуги</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" value="0" data-extra="50" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrap">
        <label for="">Ответственность</label>
        <select name="" id="">
          <option value="1000-5000">1000-5000</option>
          <option value="1000-5000">5000-10000</option>
          <option value="1000-5000">10000-15000</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="res"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вы не `.calc-row input` обрабатывыйте, а `$(this).closest(".calc-row")`,find("input")` ну или что-то в этом роде

Comment: @teran спасибо за подсказку. сделал, все работает!